# How to cache a string in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, caching

Lets say I make a get request and get this string back "ASDF". I want to cache this so that when the user isn't connected, I can just get that string from the cache and load it that way. Currently, I am doing it this way:

```
var asdf = await DefaultCacheManager().getFileFromCache(url + '/asdf'); //The url variable is the link to the server + the path
if (asdf != null && asdf.file.existsSync()) {
  //IS CACHED
}
```

But I don't think this works, because it is saying that something is cached when its not, and saying that something isn't cached when it is. Can someone please provide a code snippet of a working example? Thanks!

Comment: You can use the SharedPreference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the SharedPreference: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Comment: I want to cache it so that even with a hot restart it still is there. With Shared Preferences it doesn't exist after a hot restart.